# Bootstrap 5 Modal: Toggle Modal via Javascript

Tags: bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-5

I open a Bootstrap 5 modal and the content is loaded via ajax. In a second step I want to change the content of the modal. In my **simplified example** I do not load the content via ajax. My example works but one modal instance seems not be closed correctly, because I cannot scroll the page anymore after closing the second modal.

**My Solution:**

```js
    const open_modal = document.querySelector('.modal.show');
    if (open_modal) bootstrap.Modal.getInstance(open_modal).hide();
```

**Updated fiddle:**

https://jsfiddle.net/Phantomias/a6spcx7u/47/

In the Bootstrap documentation is a section about toggling between two modals:
https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/components/modal/#toggle-between-modals

In the bootstrap.js I found this section, but I cannot reproduce it:

```js
   const alreadyOpen = SelectorEngine.findOne(OPEN_SELECTOR$1);

    if (alreadyOpen) {
      Modal.getInstance(alreadyOpen).hide();
    }
```

```html
<div id="div_modal_container"></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ms-2 btn-open-form">Feedback</button>

<div id="div_ajax_answer_html1">
  <div id="div_modal_default" class="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header bg-secondary text-light">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Feedback</h5><button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1>First modal</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Abort</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-send-form"> Send</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="div_ajax_answer_html2">
  <div id="div_modal_default" class="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header bg-secondary text-light">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h5><button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1>Second modal</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">okay</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-open-form', function()
  {
    let ajax_answer_html = $('#div_ajax_answer_html1').html();
    let $modal_container = $('#div_modal_container');
    $modal_container.html(ajax_answer_html);
    let modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(document.getElementById('div_modal_default'));
    modal.show();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn-send-form', function()
  {
    let ajax_answer_html = $('#div_ajax_answer_html2').html();
    let $modal_container = $('#div_modal_container');
    $modal_container.html(ajax_answer_html);
    console.log($modal_container.html());
    let modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(document.getElementById('div_modal_default'));
    modal.show();
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Few mistakes here,

1. Both of the `modal` having the same ID `id="div_modal_default"`, I renamed the second modal to `id="div_modal_default2"`
2. I commented this line in both `'click'` event > `$modal_container.html(ajax_answer_html);`

Then the modal works as it should.

Please have a think again about what you actually wanna do with following code,
`$modal_container.html(ajax_answer_html);`

Hope it helps and Happy coding!

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(document).on('click', '.btn-open-form', function()
  {
    let ajax_answer_html = $('#div_ajax_answer_html1').html();
    let $modal_container = $('#div_modal_container');
    
    // $modal_container.html(ajax_answer_html);
    
    let modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(document.getElementById('div_modal_default'));
    modal.show();
  });

  $(document).on('click', '.btn-send-form', function()
  {
    let ajax_answer_html = $('#div_ajax_answer_html2').html();
    let $modal_container = $('#div_modal_container');
    
    // $modal_container.html(ajax_answer_html);
    console.log($modal_container.html());
    
    let modal = bootstrap.Modal.getOrCreateInstance(document.getElementById('div_modal_default2'));
    modal.show();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-GLhlTQ8iRABdZLl6O3oVMWSktQOp6b7In1Zl3/Jr59b6EGGoI1aFkw7cmDA6j6gD" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0-alpha1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-w76AqPfDkMBDXo30jS1Sgez6pr3x5MlQ1ZAGC+nuZB+EYdgRZgiwxhTBTkF7CXvN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="div_modal_container"></div>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary ms-2 btn-open-form">Feedback</button>

<div id="div_ajax_answer_html1">
  <div id="div_modal_default" class="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header bg-secondary text-light">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Feedback</h5><button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1>First modal</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Abort</button>
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-send-form"> Send</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div id="div_ajax_answer_html2">
  <div id="div_modal_default2" class="modal" tabindex="-1" aria-hidden="true" data-bs-backdrop="false">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header bg-secondary text-light">
                  <h5 class="modal-title">Confirmation</h5><button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">
                    <h1>Second modal</h1>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">okay</button>
              </div>
          </div>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>

<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada. Nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a condimentum vitae. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris. Facilisis volutpat est velit egestas. Urna duis convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit. Fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel. Sit amet porttitor eget dolor. Aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris pharetra et. Amet consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique sollicitudin nibh sit amet. Faucibus turpis in eu mi. Dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Tellus mauris a diam maecenas. Sit amet est placerat in egestas erat.

Odio ut enim blandit volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt eget. At ultrices mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget. Volutpat maecenas volutpat blandit aliquam etiam. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem. Mauris commodo quis imperdiet massa. Faucibus turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue. Cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Sed nisi lacus sed viverra. Nulla facilisi cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium nibh ipsum. At tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum sed. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus. Ac orci phasellus egestas tellus rutrum tellus. At tellus at urna condimentum.

Quam quisque id diam vel quam elementum pulvinar. Urna duis convallis convallis tellus id. Egestas tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor aliquam. Pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies. Sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget. Ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra pharetra. Feugiat pretium nibh ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus. Tincidunt dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in. Lectus sit amet est placerat in. Scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a erat. Fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit. Nunc mi ipsum faucibus vitae. Id volutpat lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna. Scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque. Sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget. Sed cras ornare arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum ut.

Et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis. Eget nullam non nisi est sit. Sodales neque sodales ut etiam sit amet nisl purus. Donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat in fermentum posuere. Ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae et leo duis. Nulla at volutpat diam ut venenatis tellus in. Ante metus dictum at tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus. Sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl nunc mi ipsum. Mauris nunc congue nisi vitae. Vitae justo eget magna fermentum iaculis eu non diam phasellus. Mi tempus imperdiet nulla malesuada pellentesque elit eget. At urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id.

Ac turpis egestas maecenas pharetra convallis posuere morbi leo. Dignissim convallis aenean et tortor at risus viverra adipiscing. Tincidunt eget nullam non nisi est sit amet facilisis magna. Elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu. Ut ornare lectus sit amet est placerat in. Lectus sit amet est placerat in egestas erat. Morbi blandit cursus risus at ultrices mi tempus imperdiet. Molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed. At tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus vestibulum. Diam sollicitudin tempor id eu nisl. Ut sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl. Ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur. Arcu vitae elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim. Ullamcorper morbi tincidunt ornare massa eget. Nisi scelerisque eu ultrices vitae auctor eu augue. Id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl. Purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in hac. Lorem sed risus ultricies tristique nulla.

Cursus in hac habitasse platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. Ut venenatis tellus in metus vulputate eu scelerisque. Amet volutpat consequat mauris nunc congue nisi. Eu lobortis elementum nibh tellus molestie nunc non blandit massa. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas. Urna porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim. Magna sit amet purus gravida quis blandit. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt augue. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate. Pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et tortor consequat id. Risus commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel.

Quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices. Neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam. Sit amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus in. Tempus quam pellentesque nec nam aliquam sem et. Cras pulvinar mattis nunc sed. Ut etiam sit amet nisl purus in mollis nunc sed. Faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim neque volutpat ac. Amet aliquam id diam maecenas ultricies mi eget mauris. Elementum curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum sociis. Convallis convallis tellus id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices.

Tincidunt lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue. Congue quisque egestas diam in arcu cursus. Nibh sed pulvinar proin gravida hendrerit. Pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui. Dui ut ornare lectus sit amet est. Neque vitae tempus quam pellentesque. Facilisis sed odio morbi quis. Lobortis feugiat vivamus at augue eget. Diam maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit. Facilisis leo vel fringilla est ullamcorper eget.

Ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget nunc lobortis. Sagittis orci a scelerisque purus. In pellentesque massa placerat duis. In egestas erat imperdiet sed euismod nisi porta lorem. Eros in cursus turpis massa. Nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit. Fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna et pharetra. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Elit eget gravida cum sociis. Ipsum a arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean. Cras fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium. Eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet. Commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam donec adipiscing. Cursus metus aliquam eleifend mi. Purus in mollis nunc sed id semper risus.

Odio morbi quis commodo odio. Sed egestas egestas fringilla phasellus faucibus scelerisque eleifend. Elit pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et. Feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed. In nibh mauris cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat. Sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate. Curabitur vitae nunc sed velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem. Faucibus et molestie ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis. Maecenas sed enim ut sem viverra aliquet eget sit amet. Venenatis a condimentum vitae sapien. Velit ut tortor pretium viverra. Enim facilisis gravida neque convallis. Elit ullamcorper dignissim cras tincidunt.

Sed faucibus turpis in eu mi. Proin libero nunc consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis vulputate. In ornare quam viverra orci sagittis eu volutpat odio facilisis. A arcu cursus vitae congue mauris rhoncus aenean vel elit. Etiam non quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum. Aenean euismod elementum nisi quis eleifend quam. Varius sit amet mattis vulputate enim. Risus at ultrices mi tempus. Dictum sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut. Posuere urna nec tincidunt praesent. Felis donec et odio pellentesque diam volutpat. Bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas diam in arcu. Iaculis urna id volutpat lacus.

Adipiscing diam donec adipiscing tristique risus. Molestie at elementum eu facilisis sed odio morbi quis commodo. Sed euismod nisi porta lorem. Urna cursus eget nunc scelerisque viverra mauris in aliquam sem. Cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id. Donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus ultrices in. Quam id leo in vitae turpis massa sed elementum. Id interdum velit laoreet id donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non. Tellus rutrum tellus pellentesque eu tincidunt tortor. Erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur a. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Viverra accumsan in nisl nisi scelerisque eu. At imperdiet dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi. Sapien et ligula ullamcorper malesuada proin libero. Nec feugiat nisl pretium fusce id velit ut tortor pretium. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing. Id ornare arcu odio ut sem nulla pharetra. Arcu felis bibendum ut tristique et. Dictum varius duis at consectetur lorem.

At lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Viverra aliquet eget sit amet tellus cras adipiscing enim eu. Libero id faucibus nisl tincidunt. Lectus quam id leo in vitae turpis. Habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac. Ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh. Etiam erat velit scelerisque in dictum non consectetur. Placerat in egestas erat imperdiet sed. Ac feugiat sed lectus vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed. Tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. Elit sed vulputate mi sit. Id consectetur purus ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer.

Proin nibh nisl condimentum id venenatis a. Risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus. Mauris augue neque gravida in fermentum. Eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien nec sagittis aliquam. Sit amet commodo nulla facilisi nullam vehicula. Tortor consequat id porta nibh venenatis. Laoreet sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Dui accumsan sit amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus. Tristique nulla aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id. Malesuada pellentesque elit eget gravida cum. In egestas erat imperdiet sed.

Urna condimentum mattis pellentesque id nibh tortor id aliquet lectus. Turpis in eu mi bibendum neque egestas congue quisque egestas. Vestibulum mattis ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi tincidunt. Nunc sed blandit libero volutpat sed cras ornare arcu dui. Massa enim nec dui nunc. Tellus at urna condimentum mattis. Suspendisse in est ante in nibh mauris cursus. Sem nulla pharetra diam sit amet nisl suscipit. Sed odio morbi quis commodo odio aenean sed adipiscing diam. Lacinia quis vel eros donec ac. In tellus integer feugiat scelerisque. Tempor commodo ullamcorper a lacus. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper. Nibh tortor id aliquet lectus proin nibh nisl. Tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames. Mi quis hendrerit dolor magna eget est lorem ipsum.

Velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed. Morbi enim nunc faucibus a pellentesque. Aliquet enim tortor at auctor urna nunc id. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus. Nunc non blandit massa enim nec. Commodo viverra maecenas accumsan lacus vel facilisis volutpat est. Pellentesque adipiscing commodo elit at imperdiet dui accumsan sit. Porttitor rhoncus dolor purus non enim praesent elementum facilisis leo. Dui sapien eget mi proin. Eget felis eget nunc lobortis mattis aliquam faucibus purus in. Arcu cursus vitae congue mauris. Phasellus vestibulum lorem sed risus. Ultrices sagittis orci a scelerisque purus semper. Sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut. Sit amet cursus sit amet. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor orci.

Malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet nibh praesent. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales. Viverra justo nec ultrices dui. In aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Rhoncus aenean vel elit scelerisque mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque. Et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas sed tempus urna. A pellentesque sit amet porttitor eget dolor morbi non arcu. Morbi tincidunt augue interdum velit euismod in pellentesque massa placerat. Tortor at auctor urna nunc. Tortor at auctor urna nunc id cursus metus aliquam eleifend. Mauris pellentesque pulvinar pellentesque habitant morbi. Augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at varius vel. Sit amet justo donec enim diam vulputate ut. Venenatis cras sed felis eget velit aliquet sagittis id consectetur. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Id leo in vitae turpis massa. Nec ullamcorper sit amet risus nullam eget felis eget. Erat nam at lectus urna duis convallis convallis. Id semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque. Quis vel eros donec ac odio tempor orci dapibus.

Ut faucibus pulvinar elementum integer enim. Amet nulla facilisi morbi tempus iaculis. Ipsum consequat nisl vel pretium lectus quam id leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes. Enim nec dui nunc mattis enim ut tellus. Ut consequat semper viverra nam libero. Congue eu consequat ac felis donec et odio pellentesque. Convallis aenean et tortor at. Diam quis enim lobortis scelerisque fermentum. Enim facilisis gravida neque convallis a cras semper auctor. Morbi leo urna molestie at elementum. Fermentum odio eu feugiat pretium.

Ullamcorper velit sed ullamcorper morbi. Diam donec adipiscing tristique risus nec feugiat. Porttitor leo a diam sollicitudin tempor. Quam lacus suspendisse faucibus interdum posuere lorem ipsum. Quam elementum pulvinar etiam non quam. Fermentum leo vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse. Lacus laoreet non curabitur gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim. Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci. Gravida arcu ac tortor dignissim. Amet purus gravida quis blandit turpis cursus.

Vulputate eu scelerisque felis imperdiet. Augue lacus viverra vitae congue eu consequat ac felis donec. Velit dignissim sodales ut eu sem integer vitae. Et netus et malesuada fames ac. At in tellus integer feugiat scelerisque varius morbi enim nunc. Purus semper eget duis at tellus at. Netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas integer eget aliquet. Ipsum faucibus vitae aliquet nec ullamcorper sit amet risus. Lectus urna duis convallis convallis tellus. Risus ultricies tristique nulla aliquet. Vel orci porta non pulvinar neque laoreet suspendisse interdum consectetur. Vitae suscipit tellus mauris a diam maecenas sed. Nisi est sit amet facilisis magna etiam tempor orci eu. Vitae et leo duis ut diam quam nulla porttitor. Vitae turpis massa sed elementum tempus egestas. Massa placerat duis ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt. In iaculis nunc sed augue lacus viverra vitae congue. Proin sed libero enim sed faucibus turpis.
</p>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your input. It's just a simplified example. Normally the content is loaded via ajax.

Comment: In your example we have to overlapping modals. This is not what I wanted to achieve.